autoinstall storage using lvm layout and XFS as fstype
I'm trying to configure autoinstall storage with XFS as fstype.
Using this automatically creates ext4 volume
  storage:  # This should set the interactive (lvm set) default
    layout:
      name: lvm
      match:
        size: largest
      sizing-policy: all


I do not want to use 'direct' layout to be as generic as it could be.
I tried to add a config section like:
    config:
      - type: format
        id: format-2
        volume: lvm_partition-0
        preserve: false
        fstype: xfs

but it has not effect
I tried this too:
      config:
        - type: partition
          fstype: xfs

and even this without more success:
      config:
        - type: partition
          fstype: xfs
        - name: ubuntu-lv
          volgroup: lvm_volgroup-0
          size: 100%
          wipe: superblock
          preserve: false
          path: /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv
          id: lvm_partition-0
          type: lvm_partition
        - fstype: xfs
          volume: lvm_partition-0
          preserve: false
          id: format-2
          type: format

The documentation doesn't give us any information on this topic.
I success configured a brand new server manually using the wizard and looked at the /varlog/install/autoinstall-user-data but copy / paste of parts of the config section doesn't work.
Does anybody here had it working and could share the config ?
Thanks
Olivier

Hi, answering to myself for the posterity ;-)
I should have read the doc more carefully.
It says : when using layout, the config section isn't read.
I finaly did it like this :
  storage:
    config:
    - id: first-disk
      match:
        size: largest
      ptable: gpt
      type: disk
      preserve: false
      wipe: superblock-recursive


answering to myself for the posterity ;-)
I should have read the doc more carefully.
It says : when using layout, the config section isn't read.
I finaly did it like this :
choose the largest disk without naming it directly so it can work with any kind of disk
  storage:
    config:
    - id: largest-disk
      match:
        size: largest
      ptable: gpt
      type: disk
      preserve: false
      wipe: superblock-recursive

Define partitions for boot and efiboot and the largest one for system and data
    - id: partition-0
      device: largest-disk
      size: 200M
      number: 1
      preserve: false
      grub_device: true
      type: partition
    - id: partition-1
      device: largest-disk
      size: 200M
      number: 2
      preserve: false
      type: partition
    - id: partition-2
      device: largest-disk
      size: -1
      wipe: superblock
      number: 3
      preserve: false
      type: partition

define formats
    - id: format-0
      fstype: fat32
      volume: partition-0
      preserve: false
      type: format
    - id: format-1
      fstype: ext4
      volume: partition-1
      preserve: false
      type: format
    - id: format-2
      fstype: xfs
      volume: lvm_partition-0
      preserve: false
      type: format

Define VG and LG
    - id: lvm_volgroup-0
      name: ubuntu-vg
      devices:
      - partition-2
      preserve: false
      id: lvm_volgroup-0
      type: lvm_volgroup
    - id: lvm_partition-0
      name: root-lv
      volgroup: lvm_volgroup-0
      size: 100%
      preserve: false
      path: /dev/ubuntu-vg/root-lv
      type: lvm_partition

Define mounts
    - id: mount-0
      path: /boot/efi
      device: format-0
      type: mount
    - id: mount-1
      path: /boot
      device: format-1
      type: mount
    - id: mount-2
      path: /
      device: format-2
      type: mount

And it works fine....
lsblk 
NAME                     MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sda                        8:0    0   20G  0 disk 
├─sda1                     8:1    0  200M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2                     8:2    0  200M  0 part /boot
└─sda3                     8:3    0 19.6G  0 part 
  └─ubuntu--vg-root--lv  252:0    0 19.6G  0 lvm  /
sr0                       11:0    1 1024M  0 rom  


mount |grep xfs
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root--lv on / type xfs (rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,logbufs=8,logbsize=32k,noquota)


